# How to convert the String array into bytes?

Tags: java

I an having the string of array,i need to convert to bytes,So how can i do it?

sample is

String test[] = {"Hello","Hello1"};

I need to convert them to bytes in one place and get them back in other place as string.
I need to pass in as bytes,I am having the string array,So is this way?or any other alternate mean?

Comment: string of array or array of strings?

Comment: Please explain in more detail, preferrably with some source code, what exactly you want to do and why - then we could give you much more useful answers.

Comment: Please paste the code that declares this "string of array", or is it "String array"? Did you mean: String[] array?

Comment: Do you mean you have `String[]` and you want a single `byte[]` containing a concatenation of all bytes from all `String` instances in the array?

Comment: you need to be more specific... what sort of bytes do you want? a serialised version of the string array? ASCII bytes? UTF-8? do you want delimiters for the array? also worth posting what code you have so far (SSCCE) - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily convert `String[]` to `byte[][]` by iterating the array and using

```
bytes[i] = str[i].getBytes(encoding);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String Convertthis = "i want to convert this string to byte array" 
byte[] theByteArray = Convertthis.getBytes("UTF8");
System.out.println(theByteArray.length);
```

See http://javasourceblog.blogspot.in/2012/03/array-in-java.html

Comment: You need to provide an encoding to `.getBytes()`, or you will get a random encoding depending on the platform.

Answer (score -1):

Iterate through the `String` array, append each `String` value to a `StringBuilder` Object. After completing the iteration, return `builder.toString.getBytes()

```
public byte[] stringToByte(String[] str){

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
            builder.append(str[i]);
        }
        return builder.toString().getBytes("UTF8");
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide an encoding to `.getBytes()`, or you will get a random encoding depending on the platform.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström, yes, I agree. I just provided an example of **"How to convert String[] to byte[]"**. It is up to the asker of this question to implement the desired encoding :-)

Comment: Then provide a correct example instead of a broken one. You know damn well people will copy and paste and don't understand why it suddenly breaks months later with strange characters on a different platform.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström, I appreciate your effort. I have updated my answer.